# Why Azure mandates to create a new or empty resource group when we deploy a VM using a solution template published in Market place?

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

When a vm deployment solution is published in Azure Market place. The deployment always mandates to select an empty resource group or select a new resource group as 1st step.

Why it is necessary? Is there a way we can carry out the deployment in existing resource group?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQVtg.png)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is because you are trying to create some resource(s) that Azure thinks need to be created in empty resource group.

By default, Azure do not support to deploy managed application to resource group with resources.

There are a few resources that require to be deployed to a empty RG. For example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/data-science-virtual-machine/provision-geo-ai-dsvm

The reason should be because some of the resources might overlap with existing ones. Such as address spaces, etc.

To see if there is a way we can carry out the deployment in existing resource group for your resource, I suggest to try using Powershell \ CLI \ RestAPI, etc.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Even though it enforces to select an empty resource group or create a new RG but later we can select existing vnet or create new vnet. For resource group the same should be applied. Select existing or create new.